# Multivariable Laurent Series

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

Is it possible to Laurent Expand over two complex variables? for example

$\frac{w+\tilde{w}}{(w\tilde{w})^{3}}$

where $w=i\sqrt{2}z+\hat{d}x+i\hat{e}y$ and $\tilde{w}=i\sqrt{2}z-\hat{d}x-i\hat{e}y$

Can someone point me in the right direction? i don't seem to be able to find much for more than 1 complex function..

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, depending on the domain of the function.

In your example, if you take a point on the smooth part of the pole divisor, you can find a product of annuli of small radii where the function is holomorphic. Then construct the Laurent series the same way as in one variable, by Cauchy's integral.

I'd refer to  [Shabat's book](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=h5H4AwAAQBAJ&pg=PA36&lpg=PA36&dq=shabbat%20complex%20analysis%20Laurent%20series&source=bl&ots=IQ8JdlzRUJ&sig=s9v28AWTZGuObVdTpdeWvo0fT0g&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiCu-TPkanKAhUHEpAKHYhYDGAQ6AEINTAG#v=onepage&q=shabbat%20complex%20analysis%20Laurent%20series&f=false), see page 35. It rather brief but may help.